# How to reuse value from inbound and pass it to outbound Azure APIM

Tags: azure-api-management, outbound

I have a service on Azure APIM have a parameter Token .

the client should provide the token value .
and I want to show token value in the response , How it is going to be ?

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <set-variable name="token" value="@(token)" />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the below policy to write the token value in response.

```xml
<outbound>
    <base  />
    <set-variable  name="token"  value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("token"))"  />
    <set-body>@("Token: "+ ((string)context.Variables["token"]))</set-body>
</outbound>
```

Please make sure to pass the token value in Header.

[image]

In this way, you can pass the token value in response.

Comment: That would work for sure. More generic approach would be to use set-variable inside inbound and use it in outbound, variables are preserved between sections.

Comment: @VitaliyKurokhtin Yes even declaring the set-variable inside inbound would work